# I'm trying to insert data into the database through php

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php
<form name "fav_button" action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="fav_button"  value="Add to Favorite" />
</form>

if(isset($_POST['fav_button']) ){
        $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","alaa","registration_database");
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

            }
          $query= ("INSERT INTO favs (uId, itemId) VALUES ('1','2'); ");
        }
 ?>
```

I'm trying to add data into the table favs after clicking the button "fav_button" the page refreshes and no errors show up, but the table is not updated, can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong exactly?
I'm running the query i'm using in the phpmyadmin and it's working fine.

Comment: `$query` is just a SQL statement. You need to execute it. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: how do i do so?

Comment: See the provided link. I'd advise learning the `prepared` approach first. The `query(` should only be used when all the data is static. This looks like it will be taking user input in the future.

Comment: Your `form`s `name` attribute also is invalid.

Comment: yeah I'm currently reading the link, the query is actually going to be taking the users Id and the item id from other tables and adding them to a new table upon clicking the favorite button, could you elaborate more on the forms name?

Comment: You're missing the `=`s, here `name "fav_button"`. The value from the form is going into a SQL statement though, no?

Comment: ohh true! fixing it now, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `$conn->query($query);` and it is important to run the query.. this line actually executes your query

```
    <form name="fav_button" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="fav_button"  value="Add to Favorite" />
    </form>

    if(isset($_POST['fav_button']) ){
            $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","alaa","registration_database");
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

                }
              $query= ("INSERT INTO favs (uId, itemId) VALUES ('1','2'); ");
              $conn->query($query);//this is the line which actually executes your query
            }
     ?>
```

Comment: thank you very much! works great, I'll accept your answer just gotta wait 10 min.